# I'm trying to find a code to give me a specific data of a person in the column A as per date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

If Employee A then result should show the  yesterday result for an Employee A, Employee B, Employee C here Date should be Constant and next time date should change as per day of the report(Today-1) when I Run the formula in a report sheet using different sheet saved in sepcific folder

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post the relevant code, and elaborate on exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Can you add description and code samples plz

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear.  What is the end result that you want from your script?  Let me try to decipher.  Whenever the actual date is different from a date in a certain cell you want the sheet to automatically show the employees data for the new date in the cell?  If so then you can create a selection change in the worksheet module to target that particular date cell, and when changed the code should get the employees data for that new date and display it.  That's the logic.  The code is your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` and `MATCH` to achieve this.

In cell Q14, enter the formula:

```
=INDEX($B$4:$M$9,MATCH($P14,$A$4:$A$9,0),MATCH($T$13,$B$2:$M$2,0))
```

It matches the value from column P with the values in column A to determine which row to use, and it matches the value from T13 with the values in row 2 to determine which column to use.